# Design Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Where can I start learning Windows Form designing?

For example: Microsoft Zune player, Buttons, Forms and etc.

I'm developing in C#.

Thank you all,

Amit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were going to try and write something like the Zune software I would start with WPF rather than Windows Forms. Check out some of the [WPF experiences by thirteen23](http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/) for good examples of "experience-driven" applications.

You can start learning more about [WPF on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx) or by reading [WPF Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917).

Comment: Hi Adam, you developing with WPF? that the way microsoft built the Zune sofwere? cause i've developed alreay my program, i'm trying to desgin it to look better..don't know even where to start..
Thanks Amit